Next JS 14+ automatically applies the layout file to pages without importing it and wrapping it around the content of the pages
When I created a layout.jsx file in the app directory, I discovered the layout automatically applies to the pages I created without having to import it and wrap it around the content of each page.
Why does this happen? Is there an explanation for it?

That is by design, and I assume you are talking about app routing and layout.js.
Please check documentation here
